# How to create a pie chart with Rstudio flexdashboard?

Tags: r, plotly, flexdashboard, r-plotly

I am new to Rstudio and I am tring to figure out how to create a dashboard with "flexdashboard"

Here is my dataset

````
```    Country       Refugees   
    1 Belgium         508645
    2 France         2874490
    3 Germany       10893516
    4 Ireland         142555
    5 Italy           538407
    6 Netherlands    1900518
    7 Portugal          7918
    8 Spain            89946
    9 United Kingdom 3766855
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDnHQ.png)

I am trying to create a pie chart, and here is what I enter but it does not work. After trying many variations, I never figured out how to make it work.

````
```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(plotly)

totalref <- read.csv("F:/HU/ANLY 512/Dashboarding Lab/total.xls", header = TRUE)

plot_ly(totalref, labels= ~totalref$Country, values= ~totalref$Total, type= 'pie')
 layout (title='Persons of Concern in 9 European Countries',
    xaxis = list(showgrid=FALSE, zeroline=FALSE, showticklabels=FALSE),
    yaxis = list(showgrid=FALSE, zeroline=FALSE, showticklabels=FALSE))

```
````

I think I am probably on the wrong track so any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: When you get errors and you want to seek help on SE, you have to include the error message that you get in the question. Otherwise, it's not clear what issue you're trying to overcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my remarks:

- drop the `totalref$` in the `plot_ly()` calls and use column names directly.
- there is no `Total` column in your sample data, maybe what you wanted to use is `Refugees`?
- if you use `include=FALSE`, the code chunck will be evaluated, but neither the code nor its output will be displayed. So remove this and replace it by `echo=FALSE` if you want the code not to be displayed, but the plot to appear.
- The first argument of the `layout()` function is the plot itself, so it seems a pipe operator `%>%` is missing in your code.

Using the sample data you provided, this line:

```
totalref <- read.table(header = T, text = 
"Country        Refugees   
'Belgium'         508645
'France'         2874490
'Germany'       10893516
'Ireland'         142555
'Italy'           538407
'Netherlands'    1900518
'Portugal'          7918
'Spain'            89946
'United Kingdom' 3766855")

plot_ly(totalref, labels = ~ Country, values = ~ Refugees, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside', textinfo = 'label+percent') %>%
    layout (title='Persons of Concern in 9 European Countries',
            showlegend = TRUE)
```

works fine for me. It gives the following result:

- `textposition = 'inside', textinfo = 'label+percent'`: displays the label and percent inside the graph;
- `showlegend = TRUE` displays the legend.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is working when I try with the console, but when I try to knit to flex_dashboard, I gives me an error message, and all the Observations are removed from related dataset in the General Environment. That is why I am confused. I can't figure out how to knit to flex_dashboard.

Comment: What error do you get exactly? On my side it works without any errors. Could you try with the dummy data I added to the answer.